# If the same string is in the first column of a sorted dataframe take the rows associated with the unique value and create new dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, columnsorting

What I am looking to do is for every email address that is the same, take the corresponding rows with that same email and create new dataframes and then send an email with the row information to the email address in col 1.

```
| email             | Acct # | Acct Status |
| ------------------|--------|-------------|
| janedoe@gmail.com | 1230   | Closed      |
| janedoe@gmail.com | 2546   | Closed      |
| janedoe@gmail.com | 2468   | Closed      |
| janedoe@gmail.com | 7896   | Closed      |
| michaeldoe@aol.com| 4565   | Closed      |
| michaeldoe@aol.com| 9686   | Closed      |
|jackdoe@aol.com    | 4656   | Closed      |
```

I tried something along the lines of converting the dataframe into a list by using groupby but I am stuck:

```
    df_list = [x for _, x in df.groupby(['email'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to store you data or what you want to do with it. I've chosen to store the output in a Python dictionary with  email contact as the key and all their various accounts and their status as the value. You can use a combination of groupby and drop_duplicates to extract and form the information you want.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('email').groups
df_contacts = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['email'])

result = {}     # dictionary for results

for item in df_contacts['email']:
    rows = df_grouped[item].tolist()
    my_data = []
    for x in rows:
        info = df[['Accnt #', 'Accnt Status']].iloc[x].values
        my_data.append(info.tolist())
    result[item] = my_data
```

Then you can use the data as required. For example:

```
for i, j in result.items():
    print('Send email to ', i, ' with their account info as follows')
    for z in j:
        print('Account : ', z[0], ' Status :', z[1])
```

If for some reason you really want the resulting data to go in separate DataFrames then this could be in a Dictionary of DataFrames as follows:

```
dx = {}
for i, j in result.items():
    dfx = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result[i])
    dfx.columns =['Accnt', 'Accnt Status']
    dx[i]=dfx
    
print(dx['janedoe@gmail.com'])   #as an example of accessing the data
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. What would this look like if you wanted to store the data as individual dataframes?

Comment: The issue is that DataFrame names cannot reasonably be created on-the-fly so a DF for each contact would need to go as a separate DF held in Dictionary. This is really not much different than my `result` Dictionary and it would be no easier to use the data for any practical use. But I have edited the code to provide that option. If you require something else then you need to clearly define what that is.